# csv - Creating a login system, python not properly reading from .csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to make a login system that is looped basically and whenever I try to enter the correct details that are even stored in the .csv file, it outputs as incorrect username/password no matter what I put. This code works for python 3.6 but I need it to work for python 3.2.3.

```
loop1 = False #for this bit of code (logging in)
loop2 = False #for next bit of code
while loop1 == False:
    choice = input("Login/SignUp [TYPE 'L' OR 'S']: ").lower()
    if choice == "l":
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        f = open("usernamepassword.csv","r")
        for line in f:
            details = line.split(",")
            if username == details[0] and password == details[1]:
                print("Welcome")
                break
                #this whole bit of code is meant to read from the csv and check if the login details are correct
        else:
            print("Username/Password [INCORRECT]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing:

```
if username == details[0] and password == details[1]:
```

With:

```
if username == details[0] and (password+"\n") == details[1]:
```

Comment: That's why i told you to strip the line before splitting it and checking for passwords :) See the first line of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a bug in line.split(','), try line.strip().split(',')

TL; DR: posted a proper solution there : https://github.com/cgte/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/47207293-csv-dict

I'll stuff up my answer later if needed.

Furthermore you have a poor code design here, and find yourself debugging in the middle of a loop.

So first of all : load the data file, store content to a dict.

```
    f = open("usernamepassword.csv","r")
    for line in f:
        details = line.split(",")
        if username == details[0] and password == details[1]:
            print("Welcome")
            break
```

Should become

```
    user_pass = {}

    f = open("usernamepassword.csv","r")
    for line in f:
        user, password = line.strip().split(",")
        user_pass[user] = password
    f.close()
```

or better

```
    with open("usernamepassword.csv","r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            user, password = line.split().split(",")
            user_pass[user] = password
```

eventually run python -i yourfile.py and type "user_pass" to see what is actually stored when correct go on further code.

Think of using the csv module : https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Then get username and password from input and check:

```
if login in user_pass and user_pass[login] = password:
# or better `if user_pass.get(login, None) == password:`
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: tested this, i dont know how to make any of it work @cgte

Comment: Ooop forgot to call strip()| instead of only calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to refactor your code:

```
def login(username, password):
    with open("usernamepassword.csv", "r") as csv:
        all_details = 
              [[attr.strip() for attr in line.split(",")]
              for line in csv]
        return any(
               username == details[0] 
               and password == details[1] 
               for details in all_details)

def login_action():
     username = input("Username: ")
     password = input("Password: ")
     if not login(username, password):
         raise ValueError("Username/Password [INCORRECT]")
     return True

_USER_ACTIONS = {
    'l': login_action
}

def main():
    while True:
         choice = input("Login/SignUp [TYPE 'L' or 'S']: ").lower()
         action = _USER_ACTIONS[choice]
         try: 
             if action():
                break
         except Exception as err:
             print(err.message)
```

I think your unexpected behavior comes from not stripping the values you get after splitting by `,`

Comment: @Jag: There is nothing wrong with your code in general. I have checked it under Python 3.2.3. Only regarding readability it is better to indent the last "else". Your problem results from empty space (empty string) before or after the comma in your csv file. You should take this into account, before you split the comma, as Matias has already mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking for a whole new code. I'm trying to keep it as compact as possible, was just trying to see if theres an actual fix @saeed